# meaning of the phrasal verb "run to" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

It is from this [article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-47800419).

> Amongst its findings, the survey reveals that close to half of all households cannot **run to** a week's annual holiday, even staying with friends or family.

Does that mean that the housholds cannot afford a holiday lasting a week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the households cannot afford even a one-week holiday in an year.

The same is confirmed by the table that follows the text in question (reproduced below as an image; note the highlight):

[image]